# regex matching nested parenthesis in python

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to extract all the parameters of these methods with a regex. However, due to the SAL markings, I can't get the nested parenthesis to work correctly. I have these string to parse (multi-lined):

```
STDMETHOD_(void, Method1)(
_Out_writes_to_(gradientStopsCount, _Inexpressible_("Retrieved through GetGradientStopCount") ) D2D1_GRADIENT_STOP *gradientStops,
UINT32 gradientStopsCount) CONST PURE;

STDMETHOD_(void, Method1)(
_Out_writes_to_(gradientStopsCount, _Inexpressible_("Retrieved through GetGradientStopCount") ) D2D1_GRADIENT_STOP *gradientStops,
UINT32 gradientStopsCount) CONST PURE;
```

I tried this:

```
\(((.|\n|\r)*?)\)
```

But because there are nested parenthesis for the parameters, it won't match properly. Indeed I'd like to extract everything including nested parenthesis of a string like

```
MyFunc(...anything in here including more parenthesis...)
```

Is is doable with one single regex?

Comment: Be more specific - which part of the string do you want to match?

Comment: This will require a recursive regex which supported by `regex` module of python.Are u willing to use it

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this

".*?)((.+)).+\;" with s flag to match among several lines.

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/fJ4cN3/1